# Rundeck with Ansible - execute locally or dispatch to nodes?

Tags: ansible, rundeck

Looking for any considerations on how to run an Ansible playbook from Rundeck, where there are around 100 nodes, and I have Ansible configured to use 100 forks. It seems like there are two main choices, with both having some advantages:

1. **Execute locally.** Use either the *Ansible playbook* node step or workflow step. Target nodes using the `--limit` Ansible option. Creates a tidy Ansible log with all nodes grouped together under each step.
2. **Dispatch to nodes.** Use the *Ansible playbook* node step. This allows easy filtering of the targeted nodes using Rundeck tags. Viewing execution in Rundeck should be tidy because the logs can be grouped by node, but the Ansible logs will be a bit of a mess with overlapping executions.

Is there anything else worth considering, such as a difference in performance? Any sort of best practice / more common implementation?

thanks,
chris

Answer (score 3):

We use a mix of...

- "Execute locally" *(i.e. run playbooks via command/script module)*, and
- "Dispatch to Nodes" *(i.e. anytime we use ansible-plugin for Rundeck)*.

I've found the output and organization of the ansible-plugin to be great, however there are some limitations we've run into and those were reverted to "Execute locally" option:

1. Anywhere we use `serial: 1` parameter to perform rolling restarts of services. Because the ansible-plugin is basically using 1 thread per target host, and running each with `--limit` option, it's impossible to actually serialize Ansible plays.
2. Anywhere the execution order matters. For example, we have a few playbooks where we need the first task to complete on a group of hosts before the second task starts on a different group of hosts. Similar to the above issue, this is impossible (as best I'm aware) while using the ansible-plugin.

We did find a workaround for the second issue, which was to assign each task an Ansible flag, and split the job into multiple Rundeck steps - then run the same playbook in each step but with different tags. Works, but a bit of a hassle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I've since tried using _Dispatch to Nodes_ and experimenting with the difference between using the Ansible plugin as a node step or a workflow step. As a node step, Ansible is called for every node with `limit=nodeX`, while as a workflow step it's called with `limit=node1,node2,node3`. So I'd expect using the workflow step should help in your case. It gives you the option of choosing your nodes at runtime but you lose out on the visibility in the Rundeck UI - the output's only visible in the _Log Output_ view, not in the _Nodes_ view.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this on the table first, I'm not a rundeck expert.

However, from context it sounds like you're trying to dispatch a play per node?

Let's look at an example

---

Given the below `inventory` file...

```
[all]
[all:children]
web
db

[web]
web01
web02
web03
[db]
db01
db02
```

And the below `deploy.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  forks: 5
  roles:
    - common
- hosts: web
  roles: 
    - web
- hosts: db
  roles: 
    - db
```

I can configure my infrastructure in a declariative manor, all through my `deploy.yml` - there is no other logic needed to understand what is being deployed where.

---

While it's *possible* that at some point, my `forks` will be restricted by the number of available threads, there is no additional logic needed to deploy entire stack.

Trying to chop up this playbook for parallelism and independent execution across many nodes is arguably misguided. You have to put logic for what is running where, and limits on who is executing what in order to really see efficiencies. **That overhead just isn't worth it.** Keep your logic in ansible, and follow the KISS method :).

PS - check out AWX. Has some benefits with node execution groups.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to do a play per node, really just one play against all nodes. To use your example, let's say I wanted to configure just the databases today (say there's a new db node, or I've made some change to the `db` role). I could run Ansible with `--limit=db`. Similarly, from Rundeck, I could _execute locally_ with the command `ansible-playbook deploy.yml --limit=db`. But an alternative from Rundeck is to _dispatch to nodes_ with the command `ansible-playbook deploy.yml` and select only the nodes tagged as `db` in Rundeck.

Comment: So each node executes deploy against itself? I would still recommend not going down that route. You're placing execution logic outside of the ansible context and introducing complexity for minimal gain

Comment: Yeah, I think that's effectively how it would work if run through Rundeck that way. It does sound more complex from an Ansible viewpoint, but I think from the Rundeck interface it would be more intuitive (because each node or group is selectable in Rundeck).
I suspect a factor here is whether you spend most of your time in the CLI running playbooks, or in Rundeck running jobs. Consistency of experience is useful.